# Delete digits after two decimal point without rounding its value in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

```
var num1 = 10.12345678
```

What should i do with num1 to delete digits after two decimal point without rounding its value.
I need output as **10.12**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      title: ' Delete digits after two decimal point ',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: MyHome(),
    ));

class MyHome extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomeState createState() => _MyHomeState();
}

class _MyHomeState extends State<MyHome> {
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    var num1 = 10.12345678;
    print(num1); // I need output as 10.12

    return Container();
  }

}
```

Comment: what if you have `10.1299999`? would you still to show `10.12`? honestly a cannot figure out any use case for that...

Comment: i have 10.1299999 ether in my wallet i want to show its value upto 2 decimal places

Comment: what do you want to show if you have 10.129999?  10.12 or 10.13? what do you think is more realistic value? 10.12? really?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**If you want to round the number:**

```
var num1 = 10.12345678;
var num2 = double.parse(num1.toStringAsFixed(2)); // num2 = 10.12
```

---

**If you do NOT want to round the number:**

Create this method:

```dart
double getNumber(double input, {int precision = 2}) => 
  double.parse('$input'.substring(0, '$input'.indexOf('.') + precision + 1));
```

Usage:

```dart
var input = 113.39999999999999;
var output = getNumber(input, precision: 1); // 113.9
var output = getNumber(input, precision: 2); // 113.99
var output = getNumber(input, precision: 3); // 113.999
```

Comment: toStringAsFixed rounds value

Comment: Hello, This isn't working properly for this type of decimals try:-    
113.39999999999999, 235.12560000000002, 146.44334999999998

Comment: @RakeshLanjewar What exactly not working?

Comment: I have given you the decimals in above comment, if you try to convert them it will round like 113.40

Comment: this not working for value 12.8 , result shud be 12.8

Comment: You can try it here with your values here: https://dartpad.dartlang.org/?id=ee693897fd84488525e9

Answer (score 5):

You can use intl package (https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/intl#-installing-tab-)

```
var num1 = 10.12345678;
var f = new NumberFormat("###.0#", "en_US");
print(f.format(num1));
```

Answer (score 4):

Some answers here did not work (top answer is round, not truncate).
here is a way:

```
(n * 100).truncateToDouble()/100
```

Comment: and answer with "val - val % 0.01" does not work with negative value.

Comment: Answer is correct. It works both negative&positive values.

Comment: @sphinxlike Answer is not correct. This technique is often advocated but it doesn't actually work in the majority of cases. It can't. Floating-point just isn't like that.

Answer (score 1):

if you want round the number use this.

```
 double mod = pow(10.0, places);
 return ((val * mod).round().toDouble() / mod);
```

if you just want to truncate use this.

```
return val - val % 0.01;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String toFixed2DecimalPlaces(double data, {int decimalPlaces = 2}) {
  List<String> values = data.toString().split('.');
  if (values.length == 2 && values[0] != '0' && values[1].length >= decimalPlaces && decimalPlaces > 0)
    return values[0] + '.' + values[1].substring(0, decimalPlaces);
  else
    return data.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this ----> **(0.2055).toStringAsFixed(2)**

```
    var per = 0.2055;
    
    Text( "result view -> ${double.parse((per * 100).toStringAsFixed(2))}%",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 10)),

result value -> 
input -> 0.2055
output -> result view ->20.00
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a simple solution to this problem.

```
double value = 17.56565656;
//as string
String formatted = value.toStringAsFixed(2); // 17.56
//as double
double formattedDouble = double.parse(formatted); //17.56
```

Comment: 17.56565656. toStringAsFixed(2) == 17.57.  !!!

Answer (score -2):

```
extension NoRoundingDecimal on double {
  String toDecimalAsFixed(int toDecimal) {
    var right;
    try {
      right = this.toString().split(".")[1].padRight(toDecimal, "0").substring(0, toDecimal);
    } catch (e) {
      right = "00";
    }
    var left = this.toString().split(".")[0];

    double number = double.parse(left + "." + right);
    return number.toStringAsFixed(toDecimal);
  }
}
```

Example1:
double price = 71.999999999;
print("number: ${price.toDecimalAsFixed(3)}");

`Result: number: 71.999`

Example2:
double price = 71;
print("number: ${price.toDecimalAsFixed(3)}");

`Result: number: 71.000`